# How Can I make this TicTacToe Code I wrote tell me who is the winner at the end?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Ok, so I wrote this because I wanted to write a code for tictactoe with multiple classes instead of just one class. I can not for the life of me figure out how to make it tall me who won. If anyone can help, I would be very grateful.

RUNNER CLASS

```
public class TicTacToe  
{
//runs the game
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {           
     new createWindow();
 }
}
```

BUTTON CLASS

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class XOButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{

private static int click = 0;
private String letter;


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
{
    click++;

    //Calculate Who's Turn It Is(X is always first)

    if(click == 1 || click == 3 || click == 5 || click == 7 || click == 9|| click == 11)
    {
        letter = "<html><font color = blue>"+ "X"+"</font></html>";
        this.setText(letter);
        this.removeActionListener(this);
    } 
    else if(click == 2 || click == 4 || click == 6 || click == 8 || click == 10)
    {
        letter = "<html><font color = red>"+ "O"+"</font></html>";
        this.setText(letter);

        //removes action listener so button can't be pressed again
        this.removeActionListener(this);
    }




}
public XOButton()
{
    this.addActionListener(this);
}
}
```

WINDOW CLASS

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class createWindow extends JFrame
{

private static JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");

//creates buttons to fill window
private JButton button1 = new XOButton();
private JButton button2 = new XOButton();
private JButton button3 = new XOButton();
private JButton button4 = new XOButton();
private JButton button5 = new XOButton();
private JButton button6 = new XOButton();
private JButton button7 = new XOButton();
private JButton button8 = new XOButton();
private JButton button9 = new XOButton();



public createWindow()
 {
     /*Create Window Parameters*/
        window.setSize(300,300);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        //fills window with buttons
        window.add(button1);
        window.add(button2);
        window.add(button3);
        window.add(button4);
        window.add(button5);
        window.add(button6);
        window.add(button7);
        window.add(button8);
        window.add(button9);
        window.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

Comment: after your `actionIsPerformed` function, you could call a `checkStatusOfBoard` function that will check if anyone has won

Comment: how exactly would that go? I have tried to do it before but i cant figure out how to do it within the XOButton class

Comment: you can keep track of the board using a matrix and just go through that to find who has played what

Comment: how do i keep track of where each X and O is at? I cant really do that from within the XOButton class.

Comment: You can keep a static 2D array in your XOButton class (although this is not correct architecture wise) and add an X or an O to the position of the x/o that the user clicked. Then check where the Xs and Os are after ever turn

Comment: how can i check the position of the X/O without using the window from createWindow()?

Comment: You don't need the window. See the answer @Rohit gave

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can keep track of the Xs and Os in the `XOButton`. Just look at its name. ;)

To achieve this, simply implement a member variable, like

```
private String label;
```

and maybe a getter

```
public String getLabel()
{
    return this.label;
}
```

and modify your `void actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
{
    click++;

    //Calculate Who's Turn It Is(X is always first)
    if(click % 2 != 0) // click is odd
    {
        this.label = "X";
        // set text
    } 
    else // click is even
    {
        this.label = "O";
        // set text
    }
    // remove action listener
}
```

However, you know have to evaluate the pattern to see whether any player has won. For example if `button1`, `button5` and `button9` all have `"X".equals(button.getLabel())`, then player `X` has won (full diagonal row). Same for (`1`, `2`, `3`), (`2`, `5`, `8`) and so on ...

*Above numbers assume that the buttons are arranged in a 3x3 grid.*

### Edit

I just pointed myself to the actual problem. Now there's still the problem with how to evaluate the result regarding **all** buttons. This is a little more complex if you want to do it right.

So you created two classes

- `createWindow`: manages the window and the buttons
- `XOButton`: manages user input

---

Q: Now, which class should probably be responsible of evaluating which player has won?

A: It's `createWindow`, because it holds all buttons.

---

Q: And how is it possible to 'get here' from the `void actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method in `XOButton`? An `XOButton` doesn't know a `createWindow`.

A: By implementing an `ActionListener`, just as you do to do your stuff when the `XOButton` is clicked.

Hence `createWindow` also implements `ActionListener` and everytime it creates an `XOButton` it registers itself:

```
XOButton buttonN = new XOButton();
buttonN.addActionListener(this);
```

Now you can implement a method with the signature `void actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in `createWindow` and evaluate the game result there.

### Edit 2

Now there's the problem that we cannot decide which `ActionListener` will be executed first. However, the order the `ActionListeners` are executed is decided by the `JButton` and though it's deterministic (from last to first) I don't like to rely on it.

So what you can do here is define your own `ActionListener`. This is in fact as simple as it could be - just extend the `interface`.

```
interface PostActionListener extends ActionListener
{
    // empty
}
```

Now you have to manage this sort of Event in your `XOButton`. To do this you can mostly follow the basic operations that are necessary to handle an `ActionListener`.

First you need a method in `XOButton` to register a listener of the type you defined.

```
public void addPostActionListener(PostActionListener l)
{
    this.listenerList.add(PostActionListener.class, l);
}
```

Note: `listenerList` is a `protected` member of `JButton` (more precisely of `AbstractButton`, but it ultimately boils down to the same)

Second you need to notify all listeners when the action took place. In your case as the last action of `actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)` in `XOButton`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
{
    // do your magic

    // now as the last action notify 'child' listeners
    for(PostActionListener l : this.listenerList.getListeners(PostActionListener.class))
    {
        l.actionPerformed(a);
    }
}
```

Note: This simple loop is often extracted to a separate method that, following the convention, would look like `protected void firePostActionPerformed(ActionEvent a)`.

Last but not least you change everything in `createWindow` from `ActionListener` to `PostActionListener`.

Comment: so this almost works perfectly, but the action listener for createWindow() happens before the action listener for XOButton(), which makes it so when a player wins, you have to click another button for it to register that fact

Comment: @MrRubiksMinecraft Yes, that's another design issue. We used the same event for both user input and endgame evalutation. But these are separate things and must be handled accordingly. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a 2 by 2 array. On every button click,  you set the letter entered (either X or O) on the position of the array that the user clicked. And after every click you can have a method which checks if the puzzle was won by either of the parties.

This was the approach I had, and on looking at the comments, Gabriele B-David got the same idea here before me. So I am just complementing his original answer.